# How to write a python program to print out a column of records in database

Tags: python, database

I need to write a python program to print out the data in a column of a table within database. The database I'm using is postgreSQL. The path of the table would be: server-datastation-data. Now in the table named "data", I have a column name say "column". What should I do to access the database and all the way to the column records, and print it out?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: This is barely a question it looks more like a homework assignment.

Comment: I agree, I'm kinda a dummi in python. I only wrote codes to get connected to the database, and didnot know what was the next  step. I have not run any codes yet. Where shoulhd I go look for answers next time if I have another 'homework' question?

Comment: I just answered your question below. The comments above are suggesting you append the homework tag to your question and attempt to answer the question and post problems you are running into instead of just asking for a solution to the homework assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import psycopg 

 #fill in < > with relevant values
 pgconnection = psycopg.connect('dbname=datastation', 'user=<user>') 

 curs=pgconnection.cursor() 

 statement = 'SELECT column FROM data'

 curs.execute(statement)

 records = curs.fetchall()

 for record in records:
     print record
```